# set date and time in jquery date and time picker with selenium

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am struggling with setting date in jquery date and time picker. I am using jquery date and time picker which you can find [here](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)

I am using c# to write automated tests using selenium. Here is html for datepicker

```
<input data-bind="value: dateTime, disable: sending" id="datetime" type="text" class="form-control date-time" data-provide="datepicker">
```

I tried to set date like this

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) WebDriver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('#datetime').value = '01/08/2019 10:40'");
```

But it doesnt set anything

Comment: Do you see any error?

Answer (score 0):

To set the **date** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','01/08/2019 10:40')", new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.form-control.date-time#datetime"))));
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','01/08/2019 10:40')", new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='form-control date-time' and @id='datetime']"))));
  ```